# How to create an object of custom class in iphone?

Tags: ios6

I want to create an object of my class Category. I am new in iphone development and do not know how to do it. 
Its my class .h file
Category.h

@interface Category : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *uid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

@end

in java it can be done as.
Category category = new Category();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-c we create object like this:

Category * categoryObject = [[Category alloc] init];

Now you can insert data like below:

categoryObject. uid=@"2356-4fr5-ok8u-52o8-85ki-km76-l5bt-09ij-kf65-8ij6";

categoryObject. title=@"Sample Project";

Enjoy Coding

Answer (score 0):

```
Category *category = [Category alloc]init];
```

Comment: Stackoverflow - bar is much higher - next time do some Googling

Comment: Now a days we (nonatomic,strong or weak) are used.This code will be meaningful prior to iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

## import "Category.h" in .h file

Now we have allocate memory for that by writing like this

```
Category * categoryObj = [[Category alloc] init];
```

now we can use that object where you want it like this
categoryObj.uid = @"your data";
categoryObj.title = @"your data";

I hope this will help you